# Month name to number in hive

Tags: calendar, hive, hiveql

How can I convert month name to month number in Hive ? Is there any inbuilt function available in Hive?

Eg: If I have "January" in one of the column, it should replaced to "01" using another table or using any other properties or Udf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `date_format(date/timestamp/string ts, string fmt)`

Converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of string in the format specified by the date format fmt (as of Hive 1.2.0). Supported formats are Java SimpleDateFormat formats – https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: Do I need to write UDFs ?

Comment: And one more thing is that I have added a new column 'month' in existing table and the data that i have inserted into month column is from the table name which contains 'jan'.